# Self JOIN to find the parent detail which matches with the row data -

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, join

I am trying to query in MS SQL and I can not resolve it. I have a table employees:

```
Id  Name     Surname  FatherName  MotherName  WifeName  Pincode  isChild
--  -------  -------  ----------  ----------  --------  -------  -------
1   John     Green    James       Sue         null      101011   1
2   Michael  Sloan    Barry       Lilly       null      101011   1
3   Sally    Green    Andrew      Molly       Jemi      101011   1
4   Barry    Sloan    Soul        Paul        Lilly     101011   0
5   James    Green    Ned         White       Sue       101011   0
```

I want a query that selects rows where the father name and mother name of child matches with name and wife name. For the example table, where I want to return the result of rows where father and mother name matches the name and wife name column. For eg. id=1, where John's father name James and mother name Sue matches with id 5 which returns James as first name and Sue as wife name. So my query should return (**this is my expected result**)

```
Id  Name     Surname  FatherName  MotherName  WifeName  Pincode  isChild
--  -------  -------  ----------  ----------  --------  -------  -------
5   James    Green    Ned         White       Sue       101011   0
4   Barry    Sloan    Soul        Paul        Lilly     101011   0
```

I tried with the below query but it checks for James only. How to change my query so that it checks all the names and returns the expected result.

```
select * FROM employees
where first_name like '%James%'
and wife_name like '%Sue%'
and pincode=101011;
```

Any tips on this will be really helpful. I am new to joins, need help on writing self join to get the result.

Comment: please share create table and insert data scripts for the above example.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, but also not intended as a slam against what you are working with.  Please take as constructive criticism.

Aside from VERY POOR DESIGN on the table content, getting that corrected before you get too deep into whatever you are working should be done first.  A more typical design might be having a table of people.  Now, to get the relationships you could do a couple ways.  One is that on each individual person's record, you add 2 additional IDs.  FatherID, MotherID.  These IDs would join directly back to the child vs hard strings to match against.  Take a surname like Smith or Jones.  Then, look at the many instances of a "John Smith" may exist, yes a lot, and lower probability of finding a matching wife's name of Sue, Mary or whatever else name.  But even that could lead to multiple possibilities.  Yes, you are adding a PIN, but even a computer can generate a random pin of 1234.

By having the IDs, there is NO ambiguity of who the relationship is with.

If the data were slightly altered to something like

```
Id  Name     Surname        FatherID    MotherID    SpouseID  
--  -------  -------        ----------  ----------  --------  
1   John     Green          5           6           null      
2   Michael  Sloan          4           3           null      
3   Lilly    Sloan          null        null        4
4   Barry    Sloan          null        null        3
5   James    Green          9           10          6         
6   Sue      Green          7           8           5         
7   Bill     Jones          null        null        8       
8   Martha   Jones          null        null        7
9   Brian    Green          null        null        10
10  Beth     Smith-Green    null        null        9
```

So, in this modified example, you can see right away that ID#1 John Green has parents of Father (ID#5) is James and Mother (ID#6) is Sue.  But even from this, James is a child to Father (ID#9) Brian and Mother (ID#10) Beth.  This scenario is showing to a grand-parent level capacity and that each of James and Sue are also children but to their respective parents.  Sue's parents of the Jones surname.

For Michael Sloan, parents of #4 Barry, and #3 Lilly.

And I additionally added a spouse ID.  This prevents redundancy of people's names copied all over.  Then you can query based on the child's parent's respective IDs to find out vs a hopeful name LIKE guess.

So, even though not solving a relatively simple query, fixing the underlying foundation of your database and is relations will, long-term, help ease your querying in the future.

Answer (score 0):

…

```
select *
from thetable as p -- the parent/father
where exists -- with one child at least
(
    select * 
    from thetable as c 
    where c.fathername = p.name 
    and c.mothername = p.wifename
    -- lastname?
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
        T2.*
FROM    Employee T1
JOIN    Employee T2 ON  T2.Name     =   T1.FatherName
                    AND T2.WifeName =   T1.MotherName
```